# Derivatives with respect to vector components

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, warning-messages

I am trying to work with functions of arrays, I tried the following:

```
f[x_] := x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]]^2 + x[[3]]
D[f[x], x[[1]]]
```

and got

```
2 x[[1]]
```

with the following warnings

```
Part::partd: Part specification x[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::partd: Part specification x[[2]] is longer than depth of object.
Part::partd: Part specification x[[3]] is longer than depth of object.
General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

The result is correct but how do I avoid the warnings? what is the right way to define such a function to avoid them?

Comment: You could use indexed variables `f[x_] := x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 + x[3];
D[f[x], x[1]]`  You can _not_ do `x[[1]]` or `x[[2]]` if `x` is not already a  list of length 2 for example. (unless you create such a list before hand).

Comment: @Nasser in that case, would I be able to pass list to `f[x]`? Something like `f[{1,2,3}]`
?

Comment: Or you can make an array `X = Array[x, {3}]; f[X_] := X[[ 1]]^2 + X[[2]]^2 + X[[ 3]];
D[f[X], X[[1]]]`  The Array command will create `{x[1], x[2], x[3]}`

Comment: @Nasser that seems to work, thanks. You can post it as an answer.